# How to deploy and run dart code on lightsail VPS from aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, dart, amazon-lightsail

I have VPS instance from AWS running on Ubuntu. And I want to run Dart Http server on it to allow In/Outcmming request.

I have installed the Dart SDK and Apache server.

for example, I need to run this sample code on the server and I need to access this server by its Public IP from any PC or Phone as a user.

```
import 'dart:io';

Future main() async {
  var server = await HttpServer.bind(
    InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4,
    4040,
  );
  print('Listening on localhost:${server.port}');

  await for (HttpRequest request in server) {
    request.response
      ..write('Hello, world!')
      ..close();
  }
}
```

what are the pre-requested software to make this happen?

Thanks for any kind of help I been spent around two weeks Play with this

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using EC2 for this. Additionally, when configuring it you need to make sure that "inbound" security rules allow your IP addresses to connect to it.

The easiest way to get this running will be to create a low-cost AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu 16.04/18.04 and log into it with the security credentials (using PuTTY or ssh if on Unix). There's a few guides to do that in the AWS docs.

Instructions [here](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/sdk#install-using-apt-get) will help you get the dart sdk on your server. Once you have the sdk and it is working properly (dart --version gives sensible output), you can run your program and everything should work well.

You can `scp` or copy paste your main.dart file to get it on the server.

Hope it helps.

Comment: There is really no reason to use EC2 to do this, Lightsail can handle it just fine (I work for AWS)

Also, OP states pretty clearly he already has the SDK installed.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Should I use a web server like Abache for Dart language? what its name? And the path that I should put my server code Dart in it? I hope someone to help me to answers this Q in this annoying problem. Thanks,,,

Comment: @YahYa You don't need a webserver to run a Dart server, you can run the dart code from anywhere and it will work. Make sure you are configuring the server to listen on the ip 127.0.0.1 and port 80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS) if it's a web server.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have opened port 4040 on the Lightsail firewall. Click on your instance name, then networking, scroll down, click +add another, put 4040 in the port range, and click save

If you've done this, can you curl from the local host (ssh into the box and type "curl localhost" - do you get a response?